# file_put_contents not working with $variables?

Tags: php

Hello there :) I have a question regarding the file_put_contents for PHP. I have a function for registering users, where each time someone registers, it creates a PHP script per user.

```
file_put_contents('handlers/get_trades_$email.php',"a tonne of code");
```

As you can see above, that is the script that creates the file, which is created, however it literally says "get_trades_$email.php" for the file name, rather than the desired (example) "get_trades_willsmith@bling.com.php"

any suggestions on how to fix this I will vastly appreciate ;)

Cheers,
Joshua

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single quotes does not parse variables inside. So you should do either one of the following:

```
file_put_contents('handlers/get_trades_' . $email . '.php',"a tonne of code");
```

Or

```
file_put_contents("handlers/get_trades_$email.php","a tonne of code");
```

Or

```
file_put_contents(sprintf("handlers/get_trades_%s.php", $email),"a tonne of code");
```